# How to show analytically set of points z defined by relation $|z-z_1|=|z-z_2|$ as given by its geometric description?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> How to describe set of points z defined by relation $|z-z_1|=|z-z_2|$? where $z_1,z_2\in C$

I know geometrically this represent line perpendicular to line joining $z_1,z_2$ passing through midpoint .
By Visualizing above on paper.
But **I wanted to prove this thing on paper analytically** .I tried but do not get required
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Your description looks fine to me.

Comment: I wanted to do analytically prove above representation of locus .Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the line using algebra, write $z=x+iy,z_1=a_1+ib_1,z_2=a_2+ib_2$.

Then $$|z-z_1|=|z-z_2|\\|(x-a_1)+i(y-b_1)|=|(x-a_2)+i(y-b_2)|\\(x-a_1)^2+(y-b_1)^2=(x-a_2)^2+(y-b_2)^2\\-2a_1x-2b_1y+a_1^2+b_1^2=-2a_2x-2b_2y+a_2^2+b_2^2\\y(2b_2-2b_1)=x(2a_1-2a_2)+a_2^2+b_2^2-a_1^2-b_1^2$$$$\boxed{y=\left(\frac{2a_1-2a_2}{2b_2-2b_1}\right)x+\frac{a_2^2+b_2^2-a_1^2-b_1^2}{2b_2-2b_1}}$$

This gives you the equation for a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

The set of points $z$ satisfying $|z-z_1|=|z-z_2|$ is precisely the set of points whose distances from $z_1$ and $z_2$ are equal. Namely, the set you described.

Comment: Sir I wanted to prove that analytically.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
\begin{align}
 z &= x+ iy \\
 z_1 &= x_1+ iy_1 \\
 z_2 &= x_2+ iy_2 
\end{align}
Then 
\begin{equation}
 \vert z - z_1 \vert 
 =
 \sqrt{(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 \vert z - z_2 \vert 
 =
 \sqrt{(x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2}
\end{equation}
Equate both, you will get
\begin{equation}
 (x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2
 =
 (x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2
\end{equation}
Factorize
\begin{equation}
 2(x_2 - x_1)(x - \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}) = -2(y_2-y_1)(y - \frac{y_1+y_2}{2})
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
 y 
 =
 \frac{2(x_2 - x_1)(x - \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}) }{-2(y_2-y_1)}
 +
 \frac{y_1+y_2}{2}
 =
 mx+b
\end{equation}
where $b$ depends on $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$ and the slope is $$m = -\frac{x_2 - x_1}{y_2 - y_1}$$
The slope of the line joining $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$ is
\begin{equation}
 s = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}
\end{equation} 
We get
$$ms = -1$$
Hence we get perpendicular lines.

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable substitution of $w = z - \frac{z_1 + z_2}{2}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
|z - z_1| = |z - z_2| &\implies |z - z_1|^2 - |z - z_2|^2 = 0 \\
&\implies \left|w + \frac{z_1 + z_2}{2} - z_1\right|^2 - \left|w + \frac{z_1 + z_2}{2} - z_2\right|^2 = 0\\
&\implies \left|w + \frac{z_2 - z_1}{2}\right|^2 - \left|w - \frac{z_2 - z_1}{2}\right|^2 = 0\\
&\implies \left(w + \frac{z_2 - z_1}{2}\right)\left(\overline{w + \frac{z_2 - z_1}{2}}\right) - \left(w - \frac{z_2 - z_1}{2}\right)\left(\overline{w - \frac{z_2 - z_1}{2}}\right) = 0\\
&\implies 2\overline{w}\frac{z_2 - z_1}{2} + 2w\overline{\frac{z_2 - z_1}{2}} = 0\\
&\implies \Re\left(w\frac{z_2 - z_1}{2}\right) = 0.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $w \frac{z_2 - z_1}{2}$ is a purely imaginary number, equal to $ki$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$. It follows that $iw$ and $\frac{z_2 - z_1}{2}$ are a real multiple of each other, i.e. they are parallel, though possibly opposite directions. Hence, $w$ is perpendicular to $z_2 - z_1$.

By construction, $w$ is the displacement from the midpoint $\frac{z_1 + z_2}{2}$. So, $z$ must be formed by starting from the midpoint of $z_1$ and $z_2$, and moving perpendicularly to the line segment $[z_1, z_2]$ for some distance, in some direction.

This proves the locus is contained in the perpendicular bisector. A little bit of work can be done to show the reverse inclusion by reversing the above steps.